# Capture Python script output in nested tcsh command line without supressing argparse output

Tags: python, shell, argparse, csh, tcsh

I have a multilayered problem.  This is the alias I need to use in csh/tcsh:

```
alias tools_alpha 'set tools_out=`/tools/bin/tools_alpha.py \!*` ; if ( $tools_out != '\'''\'' ) source $tools_out'
```

The goal is if the program runs it will return the name of a shell script and it will get sourced.  If -h is used, help is written to stderr but it will return empty string to stdout and nothing will be sourced.

I have made this work with perl but I would like to use Python instead as I want to add a GUI.  My first issue is that when using argparse the help gets lost.  I have debug statements that I print to stderr and that works fine.  According to documentation on argparse help is supposed to be written to stderr so I thought that would work but when running the script with -h the help is not written and the shell var doesn't contain anything I can identify:

```
> echo $myout
echo: No match.
```

If I tee to a log file I get my help text.

```
set myout=`/tools/bin/tools_alpha.py -h | tee ~/.tools_setup.stderr`
```

I cannot figure out where the help is going and what $myout has captured, its as if it is stdout.  I tried to rewrite a method of argparse making sure I am writing to stderr

```
class ArguementParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        parser.print_help(file=_sys.stderr)
        parser.exit()
```

But it didn't change anything. Any insight is much appreciated as I have exhausted all my own ideas.

**Edit**
If I pass print_help(file=sys.stderr) then I should be able to print to stderr.

What's more, this discussion makes it sound like writing help to stderr is default:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/#discussion-sys-stderr-and-sys-exit

```py
def print_help(self, file=None):
    if file is None:
        file = _sys.stdout
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)

def _print_message(self, message, file=None):
    if message:
        if file is None:
            file = _sys.stderr
        file.write(message)
```

So why isn't this working?

Comment: Error messages go to `stderr`, but help goes to `stdout`.  Look at the `print_help` method in `argparse.py`.

Comment: Thank you, but the PEP 389 doc and the code doesn't seem to match that.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: The PEP dates from 2009.  The code is current.  We'd have to study the code history (on the Python repository) and/or search `argparse` bug/issues to see whether (or when) the `help` output was switched to/from err/out.   In any case behavior is controlled by the code (and confirmed by the unittest code), not by the documentation.